# Is it possible to read excel comments with Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file(.xlsm), from which I need to extract data, including data stored as comments in some cells. Is it possible to read such comments with Pandas? How to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. As far as I am aware it is not currently possible. If you know you will be making comments when designing your spreadsheet however, you can just specify a column that will contain these comments. Alternatively, you can use something like

```
pd.read_excel('tmp.xlsx', index_col=0, comment='#')
```

to specify that any cell that starts with `#` will be regarded as a comment. From the [documentation regarding the comment argument of `pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

> Comments out remainder of line. Pass a character or characters to this argument to indicate comments in the input file. Any data between the comment string and the end of the current line is ignored.

## update

I would like to say that I know `openpyxl` can read comments. An example script would look like:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("test.xlsx")
ws = wb["Sheet1"] # or whatever sheet name

for row in ws.rows:
    for cell in row:
        print(cell.comment)
```

Perhaps you could get this to interface with your data somehow!